# Is it possible to set a start and stop time for a SignalR chat room?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, chat

I've set up a chat page within my web site using code from [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room) as a foundation, and with some minor modifications to bring it up to the newest version of SignalR, it works very nicely.

Now, what I'd ***like*** to do is set the chat room to only run during certain hours.  I can easily handle part of the issue by checking the time when the page loads and redirecting when it's too early or after hours.

But how can I test and *gracefully* redirect users out when it's closing time (sort of like a "last call" or something)?  How do I manage that?  I'd like to give the connected users a nice message and redirect them elsewhere when the chat room closes.

Comment: Sounds simple and basic but why don't you add a call on the connection to signalR which "checks" if the room is open - if not, make a call back and then redirect the user in javascript?

Comment: Could you give me some insight into how that would be done (checking the connection)?